# How to obtain the rotation angles from two successive PCA (3D space)

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

I have a rigid body moves in 3D space over 30 timesteps.
I have computed the PCAs of the rigid body over the timescale, so I have now 30 PCA (x, y, and z vectors).
Each PCA represents the body at a single time step.

I'm interested in finding the rotation angles of the rigid body.
How to obtain the angles of rotation by using two successive PCA?
Is it possible to get the rotation angles without having the rotation matrix? If yes how to do that?

Comment: Which angles do you need?  There are many ways to describe rotations with angles and there's also a question of which reference frame you would use: a fixed one or a frame relative to each previous frame?  And in what sense do you not "have the rotation matrix," given that the ordered set of normalized eigenvectors in a PCA always is a rotation matrix?  Is your concern that this matrix  actually defines eight rotations rather than one, or would it be something else?

Comment: "Which angles do you need?" In my case, I'm looking for simplicity so there are no preferences but I can say the Euler angles are fine.
"which reference frame you would use" I need to calculate the rotation angles between every two successive PCA. I mean as you said: a frame relative to each previous frame.

Comment: "in what sense do you not "have the rotation matrix," given that the ordered set of normalized eigenvectors in a PCA always is a rotation matrix? Is your concern that this matrix actually defines eight rotations rather than one, or would it be something else?". In fact, I use the SVD method to get the PCA so yes I had the matrices at the time of the calculating.
The eigenvectors for all the time steps are consistent in terms of the direction.
If you think it would be easier to solve this problem by the rotation matrix then please propose your solution.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications.  They imply that by multiplying the inverse of one matrix by the next one, you have a sequence of rotation matrices.  This reduces your question to "how do I compute the Euler angles of a rotation matrix"?  This is a nice mathematical question (but scarcely a statistical one).  The article at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html provides answers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and the article link.
I want to make sure I have got your idea correctly.
If I have R1 for PCA1, R2 for PCA2, R3 for PCA3 and so on...
Then I should have a new rotation matrix that accumulates the matrix multiplication. i.e. R = inverse(R1)*R2 then R= inverse(R)* R3 then R=inverse(R)*R4 ... for example. Is that true?
Or I need a new rotation matrix for every two PCA i.e I need to multiply inverse(R1) * R2 to get the required rotation matrix for PCA2 and inverse (R2) * R3, for PCA3 and so on?
Also, I suggest you turn your comment to an answer.
Thanks again.

Comment: It's the latter.  The algorithm is simple because the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is its transpose.  I haven't answered because the hard part concerns how to deal with the ambiguity in the rotation.  I suspect you might have gotten lucky in your particular case, because in general there simply is no way to determine which of the eight rotations is the correct one.  You need to supply some heuristic to make the right choice.  In some sense, you have to know (or assume) that the incremental rotations are *small* and then at each step select which of the eight solutions is the smallest.